# Typescript Angular2 interface "Cannot Find Name [interfacename]"

Tags: typescript, angular

I've got an interface defined as such:

```
import {AppBuild} from '../models/app-build.model'

export interface Build {
    "Name": string
    "Builds"?: Array<AppBuild>
}
```

In my component, I've imported it:

```
import {Build} from '../../models/build.model'
```

But when I try to declare a variable as a `Build`:

```
build:Build;
build.Name = "Hi";
```

I get `Cannot find name 'Build'.`

Why would this be happening?

Here's that entire function if that helps:

```
let build:Build = new Build();
build.Name = "Hi";
console.log(buildNumber)
let tempBuildArray = new Array<Build>();

return build;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably missed 'let' or 'var' keyword, and want to write variable declaration like this:

```
let build: Build;
//...Initialize your build variable with value here
build.Name = "Hi";
```

[EDIT]

If you insist on having 'Build' as interface you can initialize it like this:

```
let build: Build;
build = {Name: '123'};
build.Name = "Hi";
```

Or you can turn it into class:

```
export class Build 
{
    public Name: string;
    public Builds: Array<AppBuild>;

    constructor(name: string)
    {
         this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

and later:

```
let build: Build;
build = new Build('123');
build.Name = "Hi";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't seem to have worked. Adding the `let` made that part no longer be highlighted, but now I get `cannot set property 'Name' of undefined`.  I tried setting `build:Build = new Build()` but it's telling me it doesn't know what `Build()` is.  I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "new" an Interface. That is the problem you are having at this line;

```
let build:Build = new Build(); <----
```

Only classes can be instantiated. So you have to create a class that "implements" Build interface like below;

```
export class BuildImp implements Build
{
    public Name: string;
    public Builds: Array<AppBuild>;

    constructor(name: string)
    {
         this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

So your code will look like this;

```
let build:Build = new BuildImp(); // <-- use BuildImp
build.Name = "Hi";
console.log(buildNumber)
let tempBuildArray = new Array<Build>();

return build;
```